# Implement a List similar to Android Applications Menu

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

There is a particular functionality from Android that I would like to implement in a Xamarin.Forms/Xamarin.Android project

It is a List or Grid or some Layout that have a Scroll Index, like this:

[image: listscrollIndex]

I already create a ListView with this "FastScroll Index" via Custom Renderer, which contains an Adapter and also a scroll listener.

Is there any chance to get something like in the image?

Comment: For the content layout, have a look at [FlexLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout).

Comment: I tought on that before, but the fast scroll index feature it is what I'm interested